# Why can't I access my dynamically inserted attribute in my Object via Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a data method thats setup like this:

```
data () {
     return {
          live_count: null,
          queue: null,
     }
}
```

In my `mounted` method I retrieve data for my `queue` attribute. The data structure of my queue is there are objects inside it, and each object has an array of objects. (look at screenshot below)

[image]

Now after my retrieve is completed I periodically check if some timestamps are greater than 1 hour ago and set either true/false on a new attribute like so:

```
axios
.get(`/my-queue`)
    .then(response => {
        this.queue = response.data.queue
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
    })
    .finally(() => {
        this.loading = false;
        this._timer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('check queue rows');
            const anHourAgo = Date.now() - (60 * 60 * 1000)
            for (const [lane_id, items] of Object.entries(this.queue)) {
                console.log('lane id: ' + lane_id);
                for(const item of items) {
                    item.past_grace = item.queue_entry_time_ms > anHourAgo
                }
            }
        }, 1000)
    });
```

In my Vue.js component when I iterate over my `queue` object I can read/diplay the items from the queue fine, e.g. `queue_entry_time_ms`, but when I print out `past_grace` nothing is shown.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<template v-for="(lane, lane_id) in queue">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in lane">
        {{ item.queue_entry_time_ms }} <!-- this prints fine -->
        {{ item.past_grace }} <!-- this doesnt -->
    </template>
</template>
```

In the Vue.js debugger I can see the attribute is set like below:

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try something like `{{ item.past_grace ? "true" : "false" }} `

Comment: When I do this, all iterations print "false" even though their attribute in the object is actually true.

Comment: What is the structure of `this.queue`? If you `console.log(this.queue)` after setting `past_grace` for each item, does it look as you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this myself. For my issue, the new attribute passed to the object wasn't responsive because Vue wasn't watching for it to change.

My solution was to use Vue.set(), documented here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

It allows you to pass a new responsive attribute to an object after the object is first declared in data()

Comment: Do you know how I can correctly set my attribute? I have tried doing 
 `Vue.set(this.queue[lane_id][key], 'past_grace', true);` but this doesn't work.

Comment: I've also tried `this.$set(this.queue[lane_id][key], 'past_grace', true);` without any success either.

Comment: Have you tried to use set inside your for loop? so - `this.$set(item, past_grace, item.queue_entry_time_ms > anHourAgo)`

Comment: I tried to set the attribute to `true` first just to see I can see the attribute, I have tried both lines above, and your suggestion. Neither work, in the Vue debugger the attribute isn't showing up against the objects.

Comment: The only other solution I can offer is to set the value in the mounted method where your other reactive values are set. If Vue can react to those, then it should be able to react to the new attribute from there.

Comment: Actually, your line did work, it was an issue with my for loop. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! Best of luck with the rest of your project.